# Override activity's background that was set by theme

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog, android-theme, android-styles

I currently have an Activity for my splash screen.  The following is the way I apply a theme to the activity:

```
<application
    ...

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

SplashTheme is defined as follows:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/splash_background</item>
</style>
```

splash_backround.xml is defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/login_background"
        android:tileMode="disabled" />
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/login_siren"
        android:tileMode="disabled"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />
</item>
<item android:top="120dp">
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/splash_welcome"
        android:tileMode="disabled"
        android:gravity="top|center_horizontal" />
</item>
```

I am not calling setContentView() in onCreate() of my SplashActivity class, so thing being displayed is what is set by the SplashTheme.

A situation has come up where I want to display an AlertDialog if something fails to load upon Application.onCreate().  The splash screen is displaying at the time I use this to build, create and show the AlertDialog.  However, when I show the AlertDialog, it gets assigned the background from the Activity's theme.  Even if I define a custom style for the AlertDialog (via android:alertDialogTheme or android:alertDialogStyle) that explicitly defines a different background, it gets overruled by the background defined by the activity.  As a result, I've changed SplashTheme to the following:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
</style>
```

This now releases control of the alert dialog background as I am not explicitly setting android:background in my Activity theme. However, the window background does not account for the status bar (i.e. the background applies underneath the status bar as well).  As a result, I get a bit of jump when the splash screen transitions to the next activity that uses this same background in its layout (due to accounting for the status bar).  So, this solution still isn't working as I'd like.

If I do use the original SplashTheme (where I define android:background), is there a way to override the theme's defined android:background for an AlertDialog?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change a theme of activity once it is applied.

> Is there a way to override the theme's defined `android:background` for an `AlertDialog`?

`AlertDialog` has a constructor, which accepts `themeResId` as an input. From [docs of `AlertDialog (Context context, int themeResId)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#AlertDialog(android.content.Context,%20int)):

> Creates an alert dialog that uses an explicit theme resource.

Create a custom theme, overriding `android:background` attribute, then create `AlertDialog` using newly created theme:

```
Dialog dialog = new AlertDialog(context, R.style.my_dialog_theme);
```